# Trigger to insert data on another table, hash along the way

Tags: sql, sql-server, session, hash, coldfusion

Coldfusion/SQL Server

I have one old users table (USERS) and a new one (PT_USERS) for a new coldfusion application.

The new app was an open source product with it's own users table and login system. I've modified the app to auto login as long as the user has already logged in to the main system, and their USERS userid, username, and password exist in the PT_USERS table.

I'd like to be able to automatically add any new record in USERS to the PT_USERS table with an SQL trigger. The issue is, the new app hash()'s userid and password in PT_USERS; so when you log in it hashes your values and compares to the db's values.

It seems the hash() function uses MD5 by default, though when I specify MD5 in hashbytes() it returns the same value, but with a 0x prefix. Why is this? How can I make these the same?

Secondly, I've never written a trigger. What steps should I take to write one that will hash certain values before in inserts to the new table?

Comment: Re: *but with a 0x prefix.*  (Edit fix formatting) Because hashbytes returns binary. Humans do not read binary well, so your interface displays it as hex (denoted by the `0x`). You get the same *binary* result from `binaryDecode(hash(string), "hex"))`. As far as comparisons, A) what is the data type of those columns in PT_USERS? If it is `varbinary` you just compare the bytes. If it is `varchar` just prepend `0x` to your CF string. B) Are the USERS table column hashed?

Comment: I think the following links might be helpful in writing your trigger: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178110.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190752.aspx Sorry I can't be more helpful; it's been years since I've written triggers in TSQL